# go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen not downloading/installing stuff in the directory it should do so

Tags: go, gqlgen

I'm in a directory and I run
`go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen`

no folders or files get added. I tried running the same command above with the `-u` and `-v` flags and I do get verbose output meaning stuff is being downloaded, etc. But still no new folders or files show up.

This is what I get when I run `go env` if this helps at all

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="arm64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/myuser/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="arm64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/myuser/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/myuser/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.16.6/libexec"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/go/1.16.6/libexec/pkg/tool/darwin_arm64"
GOVCS=""
GOVERSION="go1.16.6"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -arch arm64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/my/5h457w2j641_0h2p1ll6tj940000gn/T/go-build1188675971=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: What new files and folders are you expecting? `go get` updates the entries in go.mod

Comment: Check /Users/myuser/go/bin.